# One tagname, multiple attrs - faster to stem queries with filter or use multiple selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, selector

I'm wondering which of the following jQuery queries is going to be faster. I'm looking to match any span tags that have either an src attribute or a data-src attribute.

```
var a = $('span[src],span[data-src]');


var b = $('span').filter('[src],[data-src]');
```

My gut feeling is (b) but there may be optimisations I'm not aware of.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Based on a quick test with 100 x `span[src]`, 100 x `span[data-src]`, and 100 x `span` elements: (a) came out around 4 - 8 times faster depending on the browser. On IE8 it was a lot faster (about 50 times) and on IE6/7 about the same.

<strike>What I'm wondering is why is it faster?</strike>

In case (a) jquery delegates the entire selector query the native `querySelectorAll` where available. So what looks like a slower query is actually very fast on modern browsers.

Comment: You could do some profiling and find out ;)

Comment: True, but its worth asking first :)

Comment: 100 iterations arent worth profiling. try doing it with 5000 of each and see what's faster.

Comment: @DoXicK its a good point. But scaling up will just get more accurate numbers to compare. So far they are of magnitudes difference so I don't get a lot from greater accuracy. If I scaled up the complexity of the DOM (deep nesting with complex structures) it might tell me something new. Right now I'm trying to understand why (a) would be so much more efficient. I'll report back when I get the answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have just done some tests and i think i already know why (A) is faster: It selects all spans and only adds them to the return if they have src, same for data-src. B takes all span, adds them to result, then passes that to a new function, and does the same as A already did. On firefox A is about 3 times faster for 100 iterations over 6000 spans. (750ms vs 2500ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At http://jsfiddle.net/B9Vmy/1/ i ran some tests (use firebug for the console stuff)

for 6000 spans (2000 spans,2000 with src,2000, 2000 with data-src) this ran in about 8ms so the selection part is neglectable. What makes this so slow is the creation of the jQuery objects (jQuery(element)).

While A does that only once for only the returned results, B does it for every element, after that uses those results and does that again for the returned results.

And then there's the sizzle engine possibly being used for selecting the elements... Take a look at the Filter timing for a laugh :-)

Comment: Thanks for running the tests. The interesting thing here is that in case (a) jquery delegates the whole dom query `'span[src],span[data-src]'` to the native `querySelectorAll` method which returns a non-live nodelist and thats the end of it. In case (b) jquery uses `getElementsByTagName`, loops through the live nodelist to build an array, then hands the result to `filter` which uses Sizzle to parse the attrs in JavaScript - hence the slower result.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a hypothesis, more based on logic than test.

In first case, the selector will select the `span` with `src` attribute.

In second case, the selector will select all `span` and then filter `span` with attr `src`.

So, first will be faster.

If I am wrong, correct me

Comment: +1 because testing confirms first is faster. But won't it have to do two passes as @SikuSikuCom said?

Answer (score 1):

The first version will do **two** passes of the complete DOM tree; whereas the second one only **once**.

The real answer requires a profiling on your specific case i.e. depending on how complex your DOM is. Also, different jQuery version might result in different results.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Although (a) seems to be faster for my (admittedly simple) text case.

Comment: +1 because its a good point about the two passes despite it being the faster.